# Задача с магическим массивом

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Падает решение задачи на последнем тесте выдавая Runtime error. Подскажите где в коде может быть ошибка.

> Есть массив состоящий из n целых чисел a1, a2, ..., an. Нужно посчитать количество магических индексов в массиве *а*. Индекс *x* называется магическим, если он соответствует следующим правилам:
>
> 1. 1 < x < n.
> 2. ay ≤ ax, для каждого y (1 ≤ y < x).
> 3. ax ≤ az, для каждого z (x ≤ z < n).
>
> **Вводные данные:** Первая строка содержит целое число T, где T - количество тестов. Первая строка каждого теста содержит целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^6), где n - размер массива a. Вторая строка каждого теста содержит n целых чисел a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 10^6), что дает массив a.
>
> **Вывод:** Для каждого теста выведите в отдельной строке количество магических индексов в массиве a.
>
> **Примеры Ввода/Вывода:**
>
> ```
> +------------------+-------------------+
> | стандартный ввод | стандартный вывод |
> +------------------+-------------------+
> | 2                | 3                 |
> | 8                | 1                 |
> | 2 1 3 4 6 5 7 9  |                   |
> | 6                |                   |
> | 4 2 7 9 8 10     |                   |
> +------------------+-------------------+
> ```

В своем решении я сначала считывал весь массив *а*, а потом проверял каждый элемент соответствует ли он этим требованиям.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio( 0);
    int t, n;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for( int i = 0; i < t; i++ )
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int* nn = new int[n];
        int rez = 0;
        for( int y = 0; y < n; y++ )
        {
            scanf("%d", &nn[y]);
        }
        for( int y = 0; y < n; y++ )
        {
            if( y > 0 && y < n-1 )
            {
                bool ats = true;
                int q = y; // q = 1
                while(q != 0)
                {
                    if( nn[y] < nn[q-1] ){ats = false; break;}
                    q--;
                }
                int g = n - 1;
                while(g > y)
                {
                    if( nn[y] > nn[g] ){ats = false; break;}
                    g--;
                }
                if(ats == true){rez++;}
            }
        }
        printf ("%d \n", rez);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так может просто по времени не проходит? Да и память не мешало бы освобождать...

Comment: @AnT тогда что лучше изменить чтобы ускорить?

Comment: @AnT delete [] nn; не исправило ситуацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ускорения можно использовать следующее:

Проходим массив слева направо, поддерживая текущий максимум на каждый момент. Помечаем элементы, которые не меньше текущего максимума.

Проходим массив справа налево, определяя текущий минимум (с конца). Элементы, которые не не больше текущего минимума, и одновременно помечены при первом проходе - магические.

Comment: Я правильно вас понял https://pastebin.com/PeAdV9gr ?

Comment: Похоже, да. Память только под массивы не освобождается.

Comment: осободил память под массивы, но ответы не правильные выдает

Comment: [ideone](https://ideone.com/f0Lt6o) работает

Comment: спасибо огромное. Это у меня ошибка была с декларацией переменной y в циклах которые слева направо и справа налево проходят массив :) спасибо еще раз!